# How inject the Activity to object that is being injected to the Activity?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have this module:

```
@Module
public class UserProfileModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    UserProfileController providesUserProfileController() {
        return new UserProfileController();
    }

}
```

and this component:

```
@Component(modules = {UserProfileModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(UserProfileActivity activity);

}
```

So far, in My `UserProfileActivity` I can `@Inject`an `UserProfileController`. But now, I need to inject the `UserProfileActivity` to the controller. I mean, inject each other.

I could do it by calling a `UserProfileController` setter in `UserProfileActivity`: `setActivity(this);`, but it would be nice if can be automatic.

How can achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters: add it to the constructor. Then declare that dependency.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
UserProfileController providesUserProfileController(UserProfileActivity activity) {
    return new UserProfileController(activity);
}
```

After doing so dagger will complain about not being able to provide `UserProfileActivity` unless you already do so. If you don't, add another module, or just provide the dependency from that same module. The actual implementation follows, first we need to fix your code.

`@Singleton` is a dependency on **top** of the hierarchy. You can't—or at least *should not*—have an activity dependency for a `@Singleton` annotated object, since this will probably cause bad smells and/or memory leaks. Introduce a custom scope `@PerActivity` to use for dependencies within your activities lifespan.

```
@Scope
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface PerActivity {}
```

This will allow for correct scoping of the object. *Please also refer to some tutorials about dagger, since this is a really important issue and covering everything in a single answer would be too much. e.g. [Tasting dagger 2 on android](http://fernandocejas.com/2015/04/11/tasting-dagger-2-on-android/)*

The following uses the latter approach of the aforementioned 2 options by expanding your module:

```
@Module
public class UserProfileModule {

    private final UserProfileActivity mActivity;

    public UserProfileModule(UserProfileActivity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    UserProfileActivity provideActivity() {
        return mActivity;
    }

    @Provides // as before
    @PerActivity
    UserProfileController providesUserProfileController(UserProfileActivity  activity) {
        return new UserProfileController(activity);
    }

}
```

If you now use your component `Builder` you can create a new instance of your module with the activity as an argument. The dependency will then correctly be supplied.